# My list view is empty

Tags: java, android

I tried several ways and either i get the content and no action bar or i get the action bar and no content. The activity must be a fragment but is being really hard to et it to work...

```
package ribeiro.amaranteturismo;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import ribeiro.amaranteturismo.rss.FeedActivity;

public class opcaoNoticias extends Fragment {

View myView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.noticias, container, false);
    new noticia();
    return myView;
}

public class noticia extends FeedActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isImageVisible() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDateVisible() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFeedUrl() {
        return "http://feeds.arstechnica.com/arstechnica/open-source?format=xml";
    }
}
}
```

I just get the action bar and a blank page

Comment: You're not populating it.

Comment: Can you explain please? Im new in android programming so sorry for my bad skills

Comment: Any way to keep it in a fragment? I´m not able to do it...

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing nothing to the ListView, i don't know what are your expecting to show in the list but you need at least three basic steps

1. Find and instantiate your ListView
2. Create an Adapter to handle your items
3. Set the adapter as the ListView adapter.

Example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.noticias, container, false);

    List<News> news= getYourData();

    ListView newsListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newsListView);

    ArrayAdapter<News> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<News>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, news);   // This layout is the layout of each line on the adapter

    newsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

When i read "noticia" i wonder if you are Brazilian or speak portuguese, is it's the case, try ask your questions in the SO-PT, there's a good community there too :).

The [Alura blog's](http://blog.alura.com.br/criando-uma-lista-com-listview-no-android/) have a simple tutorial about that.(In portuguese).

And there are another in [English](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm).